# how to exude an entire group if that group contains a value in a certain column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is an example of the three types of tables I have

```
    CREATE TABLE TestCs(
    [DefendantNumber] VARCHAR(60),
    [FileNumber] VARCHAR(60),
    [ReferralDate] datetime,
    [BookedFirstName] VARCHAR(60),
    )

        INSERT INTO TestCs VALUES ('1111','510-1','2019-01-01','Mike')
        INSERT INTO TestCs VALUES ('1111','510-2','2019-01-01','Mike')
        INSERT INTO TestCs VALUES ('2222','510-3','2019-01-02','John')
        INSERT INTO TestCs VALUES ('3333','510-4','2019-01-04','Kelly')
        INSERT INTO TestCs VALUES ('444','510-5','2019-01-04','Lamar')

    CREATE TABLE Testcharge(
    [FileNumber] VARCHAR(60),
    [ChargeDescription] VARCHAR (60)
    )

    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-1','Mu')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-1','St')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-2','Bu')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-2','Po')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES ('510-3','Po')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES ('510-3','Sp')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-4','Po')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-5','Ra')
    INSERT INTO Testcharge VALUES('510-5','Bu')


CREATE TABLE TestEvent(
[FileNumber] VARCHAR(60),
[EventCode] VARCHAR (60)
)

INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-1','TR')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-1','HRL')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-1','CSCT')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-2','PREL')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-2','CSCT')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-3','GJ')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-3','DIV')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-3','CSCT')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-4','FLW')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-4','CST')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-5','CAP')
INSERT INTO TestEvent VALUES('510-5','CSCT')
```

I was able to link these tables using the following query

```
SELECT cs.DefendantNumber,
cs.FileNumber,
cs.ReferralDate,
cs.BookedFirstName,
chrg.ChargeDescription,
ev.EventCode,
chrg.ChargeDescription 
FROM TestCs AS cs INNER JOIN Testcharge AS chrg
ON cs.FileNumber=chrg.FileNumber LEFT JOIN TestEvent AS ev 
ON ev.FileNumber=cs.FileNumber
WHERE DefendantNumber IN (SELECT DefendantNumber FROM TestCs GROUP BY DefendantNumber HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
```

From the table I get from the query above I want to make sure that I am able to get the FileNumber of those who don't have a certain charge description. For instance, I want to make sure that I get the `FileNumber`s of those who don't have a specific type of charge. Lets for instance the `FileNumber` of those who don't have a 'Ra' `ChargeDescription`

I used the following query at the end

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TestCs AS cs2 WHERE cs2.FileNumber=cs.FileNumber AND chrg.ChargeDescription='Ra')
```

However it is not doing what I intended. For instance I want to exclude the `FileNumber`s of those who have a `"Ra"` in the `ChargeDescription` column. Accordingly, I should not be able to see the `510-5`. How do I go about excluding an entire group if that group of `FileNumber`s that contain a certain value in `ChargeDescription` column?

The only values that should appear are

```
FileNumber  DefendantNumber
510-3   2222
510-3   2222
510-3   2222
510-3   2222
510-3   2222
510-3   2222
510-4   3333
510-4   3333
```

Comment: `and ChargeDescription <> 'Ra'` in your where clause?

Comment: You just want the FileNumber column to be NULL if the ChargeDescription for any row has a ChargeDescription of 'Ra'. So defendant 2222 would show the file number and would 3333. But in the rows for 444 it would show NULL? Or do you want to exclude those rows entirely?

Comment: @SeanLange I want to exclude all the rows of FileNumbers containing 510-5 because the ChargeDescription for the group associated with 510-5 has 'Ra'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery with NOT EXISTS for this.

```
SELECT cs.DefendantNumber,
    cs.FileNumber,
    cs.ReferralDate,
    cs.BookedFirstName,
    chrg.ChargeDescription,
    ev.EventCode,
    chrg.ChargeDescription 
FROM TestCs AS cs 
INNER JOIN Testcharge AS chrg ON cs.FileNumber = chrg.FileNumber 
LEFT JOIN TestEvent AS ev ON ev.FileNumber = cs.FileNumber
WHERE cs.DefendantNumber IN 
    (
        SELECT DefendantNumber 
        FROM TestCs 
        GROUP BY DefendantNumber 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Testcharge c 
        WHERE c.FileNumber = cs.FileNumber 
            AND c.ChargeDescription = 'Ra'
    )
```